# Java - I need a custom spring filter that should be called after http response

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I have an xml file (applicationCtx-security.xml) where all spring security filters and custom filters and their beans are defined.
I need to implement a custom filter which should be called after any http response, so that I can clear my User Principal after every http response.

Already tried SecurityContextPersistenceFilter

```
public class ResponseFilter extends SecurityContextPersistenceFilter implements Filter{

    private static final Log log = LogFactory
            .getLog(ResponseFilter.class);

public static final String USERNAME_KEY = "username";

public ResponseFilter() {
    System.out.println("Inside constructor of ResponseFilter");
}
```

xml :

```
<beans:bean id="securityContextPersistenceFilter" class="org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter">
        <beans:property name='securityContextRepository'>
            <beans:bean class="com.web.ResponseFilter">
            </beans:bean>
        </beans:property>
    </beans:bean>
```

My implemented code doesnot gets called.
ANy suggestions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to register a filter as a bean. But for it to work you have got to register your custom filter inside your Spring Security config, it has to have `doFilter` method overridden for some custom behavior, in your case output of the message - a constructor is designed only for the initialization of the class in Java Programming Language.

That's how it is done with annotations, you have to register this config as a bean in your XML file instead.

```java
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

// constructor

  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
  // custom configuration of your http

  //register the filter
  http.addFilterAfter(new ResponseFilter(), ResponseFilter.class);
  }
}
```

Also, don't forget to put your filter in the chain in the overridden `doFilter` method like this:

```
@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, 
FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {
  // other code is omitted for brevity
  //move on to the next filter in the chains
  filterChain.doFilter(req, res);
}
```

`SecurityContextPersistenceFilter` is already a filter so you don't need to implement Filter and it is not the filter class that I would suggest to implement in the most of cases - it is better to extend `GenericFilterBean` instead in the most of the cases.

Answer (score 0):

Your filter is missing `doFilter` you need to override that.

A sample filter will look like this

```
@Component
public class TransactionFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void doFilter
      ServletRequest request, 
      ServletResponse response, 
      FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

        HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        LOG.info(
          "Starting a transaction for req : {}", 
          req.getRequestURI());

        chain.doFilter(request, response);
        LOG.info(
          "Committing a transaction for req : {}", 
          req.getRequestURI());
    }

    // other methods 
}
```

Whatever you put before chain.doFilter it will be executed before the servlet.

Everything you put after it will be executed after the servlet service() method returns.

So you can put your logic after `chain.doFilter(request, response);` call.